# Убираем таксономию(/?brand=...)

Tags: javascript, php, wordpress

Есть код. Данная тема не дубликат других тем! Приведен конкретный пример! Данный код представляет кнопку при нажатии на которую происходит фильтрация товара. При нажатии в адресной строке появляется небольшое дописывание по типу
/?brand=Название бренда. Как избавиться от /?brand= и оставить только      /Название бренда.
Может быть какой-то код редиректа. Или код скрытия таксономии из адресной строки. Или плагин какой.

Мой код кнопки:

```
                        <div class="element">                   
                        <? foreach($brand_list as $brand){?>
                        <div class="<?if (in_array($brand->slug, $brand_array)) {?>active<?php }?>">
                        <label for="<?=$brand->name;?>">
                        <img src="<?=get_field('изображение', 'term_'.$brand->term_id)['url'];?>" />
                        <input  onchange="this.form.submit()" type="checkbox" id="<?=$brand->name;?>" name="brand" value="<?=$brand->name;?>">
                        </label>
                        </div>
                        <? } 
                        ?>
                        </div>
```

Comment: @Эдуард это не дубликат. Данный скрипт не работает на этот случай. Я привел конкретный пример! Я этот скрипт и выкладывал в том посте! Уберите -1, где модераторы...

Comment: @Lemp, модераторы тут) Первый комментарий - не приговор, но предположение. Вас вопрос не отмечен как дубликат, т.к. для этого недостаточно голосов за это. Вот если и когда сделают дубликатом - тогда зовите - попробуем разобраться)

Comment: @ЮрийСПб из-за неверных предположений падает рейтинг...